# Laravel GroupBy with Many-to-Many relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I have a table structure that looks like this:

```
id  | group          | category
1   | widgets        | fonts
2   | javascript     | framework
3   | javascript     | ui
4   | javascript     | slider
```

Is there an eloquent way to group "many-to-many" results such that it outputs something similar to:

```
"widgets": 
[
    {
      "category": "fonts",
    },
],
"javascript": 
[
     {
       "category": "framework"
     },
     {
       "category": "ui"
     }
     {
       "category": "slider"
     }
 ]
```

I have tried something like

```
 Model::with('tech' => function ($q) {
            $q->get()->groupBy('group');

        })->get();
```

Comment: You are looking for something like this maybe https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-groupby

Comment: Yes, I am but I can't seem to achieve it in an eloquent way with the example "with" method I showed.